# using enumerations as a parameter in a function

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I can see that you can use enumerations.

In C# I can create a function like,

```
enumertation MyEnum
{
    Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds, Spades
}

MyFunction(MyEnum CardSuit)
```

And when I call MyFunction when entering the parameter CardSuit it will pop up with the available values allowed for this parameter. Its quite handy when calling a function rather than having to remember the allowed values etc.

Is it possible to do something like this in Matlab?

I have been reading this mathwork [page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-enumerated-data-in-simulink-models.html) but I can't get the desired result.

Comment: What about this: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html ?

Comment: Are you asking how to create an enumerated type, how to get something like [function hints](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/10/20/function-hints/) to pop up and tell you what values an input can have (not likely possible), or both?

Comment: @gnovice I know how to create enumerations. I would like (and don't believe it is possible) in a function I put one of the parameters as a enumeration (eg classdef Suits) and when calling the function and enter the parameter the list of possible values pops up

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with almost the same syntax using [enumerations](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html):

```
% In an m file called Suits
classdef Suits
   enumeration
      Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds, Spades
   end
end


% In another MATLAB script / function / class
% If you tab-complete after "Suits.", you will be prompted with options.
>> disp( Suits.Clubs ); 

Clubs % This is a 1x1 Suits object
```

The [operators on enumerations](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/operations-on-enumerations.html) documentation shows that, unless you specify a different return type from the class, the enumeration objects can be treated as chars most of the time.